# Filtering map with list of lists values

Tags: java

I am trying to use streams to filter a map. So the map is of the form

`<Street,List<Houses>>`

where both `Street` and `Houses` are classes. The `House` class has field called `color` which I want to filter on. So basically I want to filter this map to obtain a map that has `Street` as keys and `House` of color `blue` as values, i.e

`<Street,List<Houses>>` where `Houses.color = blue`

Any idea of how to do this with streams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good usecase for a `Stream`, indeed

```
map.entrySet()
   .stream()
   .collect(Collectors.toMap(
           Entry::getKey,
           e -> e.getValue() // List<Houses>
                 .stream()
                 .filter(h -> h.getColor() == Color.BLUE)
                 .collect(Collectors.toList())
   ));
```

---

A trick to make the `Stream` flow more readable

```
map.entrySet()
   .stream()
   .collect(toMap(Entry::getKey, filterBy(Color.BLUE)));
```

And the `filterBy` method

```
Function<Entry<String, List<MyClass>>, List<MyClass>> filterBy(final Color color) {
    return e -> e.getValue()
                 .stream()
                 .filter(s -> s.getColor() == color)
                 .collect(toList());
}
```